# Static files not being served in nginx properly

Tags: django, nginx

I'm running a Django application with gunicorn and nginx. I have a server-side folder structure that looks like the following for my static files:

```
+-- mysite.com/
    +-- public/
        --- favicon.ico
        --- robots.txt
        +-- bookmarks/
            --- bookmarks.html
        +-- static/
            --- base.js
            --- other.js
```

My nginx config is fairly straightforward at the moment:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com

    location /static/ {
        autoindex off;
        root /home/myuser/mysite.com/public/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Accessing any file within `/static/` works just fine, but when I try to access my robots.txt file, I get a 404 - File Not Found. Adding a separate rule fixes this:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/myuser/mysite.com/public/robots.txt;
}
```

Must I create a rule per static file / folder, or is there some blanket way to handle this? I'd love for any URL of the form `mysite.com/some-file-here.txt` to return `some-file-here.txt` assuming that it exists in my `public/` folder on the server. In my example, accessing `mysite.com/bookmarks/bookmarks.html` should return that file, as it is present on the server-side file system.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current Nginx configuration directs requests to the /static/ URL path to files under /home/myuser/mysite.com/public/static/, which works well for those specific static files. However, for other files like robots.txt or any arbitrary file in the public/ directory, Nginx does not know to serve them without explicit instructions. This is why your robots.txt file was not found until you added a specific rule for it.

Try this :

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /home/myuser/mysite.com/public/; # Set the root for the entire server block

    location /static/ {
        autoindex off; # Since root is already specified, static files are served directly
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the `$uri/` portion of the `try_files` command in my example, as the site root was returning a 403. Once I did that, it worked great. Thanks!